# gRPC client do not dispose Channel

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, asp.net-core, grpc

I'm developing .net core 2.0 application with gRPC and find out a problem: after delete reference to instance of my gRPC client class, there still channel that use resourses (memory and processor).
Example code:

```
public class MyClient : ClientBase
    {
        public MyClient(Channel channel) : base(channel)
        {
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<MyClient>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Creating {i} instance");
                list.Add(new MyClient(new Channel("127.0.0.1:61783", ChannelCredentials.Insecure)));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("press enter to list = null");
            Console.ReadLine();
            list = null;

            Console.WriteLine("press enter to GC.Collect();");
            Console.ReadLine();
            GC.Collect();

            Console.WriteLine("press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

If u run example, u'll see that 10% (on my PC) used by this application. Even after *list = null* and *GC.Collect()*

The reason i suppose is  **ClientBase** do not call **Channel.ShutdownAsync()**.

So the question is:

**What is the better way to resolve problem?**

p.s. actually i use a "generated by the protocol buffer compiler" Client

```
Client: Grpc.Core.ClientBase<TDto>
```

and i can't explicitly change finalizer in generated class

Comment: Why don't you shutdown channels yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best solution: i think best practice to dispose resources with using{} or at finilize() method...

Comment: You are working with third-party library which is not intended to be used like this (nothing there implements `IDisposable`, even channel), so best way in this case would be explicitly shutdown channels when you are done with them and not rely on anything (like garbage collector) to do that for you. Well, it's always best to not rely on GC to release some resources that you can release yourself anyway.

Comment: @TimurLemeshko make you client implement `IDisposable` and in the `Dispose` method call the `base.Channel.ShutdownAsync()`. This will allow you to now call Dispose on the clients and release resources or wrap them in `using` so that it will be done for you when they go out of scope

Comment: @Nkosi there is no `base.Channel` there. But even if there were - `ShutdownAsync()` returns `Task`, so doing just `ShutdownAsync()` in dispose seems not right (and doing `ShutdownAsync().Wait()` seems not right either).

Comment: @Evk yeah I am now looking at the API and realized there is no access to the base channel. It would have to hold on to a local field.

Comment: I am doing this now. However I found that ShutdownAsync().Wait() takes about 10 seconds :O. Did you experience this?

Answer (score 1):

Possible suggestion would be to make the client implement `IDisposable` and in the `Dispose` method call the `Channel.ShutdownAsync()`.

```
public class MyClass : Client, IDisposable {
    Channel channel;
    private bool _isDisposed = false;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public MyClass(Channel channel)
        : base(channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.channelDisposing += onDisposing;
    }

    public Channel Channel { get { return channel; } }

    private event EventHandler channelDisposing = delegate { };

    async void onDisposing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await channel.ShutdownAsync();
        channel = null;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (!_isDisposed) {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        // No exception should ever be thrown except in critical scenarios.
        // Unhandled exceptions during finalization will tear down the process.
        if (!_isDisposed) {
            try {
                if (disposing) {
                    // Acquire a lock on the object while disposing.
                    if (channel != null) {
                        lock (_lock) {
                            if (channel != null) {
                                channelDisposing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                // Ensure that the flag is set
                _isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to now call `Dispose` on the clients and release resources or wrap them in `using` so that it will be done for you when they go out of scope.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var list = new List<MyClient>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Creating {i} instance");
            list.Add(new MyClient(new Channel("127.0.0.1:61783", ChannelCredentials.Insecure)));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("press enter to dispose clients");
        Console.ReadLine();
        list.ForEach(c => c.Dispose());

        Console.WriteLine("press enter to list = null");
        Console.ReadLine();
        list = null;

        Console.WriteLine("press enter to GC.Collect();");
        Console.ReadLine();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't (am I?!) change class MyClient couse it is auto-generated by Grpc (see my ps in post). Only if u know how to change it using Grpc generator....

Comment: @TimurLemeshko Then create another class that inherits from `MyClass` and implements `IDisposable` provided  that the generated class is not sealed. My assumption was that you were in control of the `MyClass` code.

Comment: I don't really like this way of doing it. Calling method which returns `Task` in dispose (even with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`) doesn't look right. Better to allow caller direct access to `ShutdownAsync`, then it can do something like `Task.WhenAll()` for them, and in general integrate that into already async codebase.

Comment: @Evk Yeah, I tend to agree. That is why i exposed the `Channel` property to have that route available. I know it is not pretty. It's just a suggestion till a better one comes along. That 3rd party dependency looks poorly designed which forces this undesirable workaround.