# gRPC should I shutdown a client channel in c#?

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I have implemented a gRPC client in C#.
  Should I shutdown the channel in the destructor?

```
private readonly Channel channel;

~MyClient()
{
    this.channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
}
```

Comment: No, you should only clean up unmanaged resources in a destructor. The correct place to do it is in `Dispose()`.

Comment: First, it is better to call it -  `finalizer`. Second, it is better to use Dispose pattern. You don't use unmanaged resources here.

Comment: In general order, you should not use the object destructor as you would do it in C++ dispose wil be in 99% of the time your best friend. unless you are dealing with unmanaged resources :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gRPC client do not dispose Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594441/grpc-client-do-not-dispose-channel)

Comment: @MatthewWatson or in this case: `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()`

Comment: @Ortiga thanks for your suggestion, I find a code example a bit messy there. But in general you are right.

Comment: @MatthewWatson could you please make an answer with a code sample